# Сделать функцию которая возвращает неуникальные значения из масива JS

Tags: javascript, функции

**Помогите пожалуйста с кодом**

Мне нужен код который возвращает неуникальные значения из масива.
Пример:

```
getDuplicates([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6]) === [1, 3]
getDuplicates(['last', 'ball', 'game', 'last', 'game']) === ['last', 'game']
```

[image: Допиши функцию, которая будет возвращать все не уникальны значение из массива.]

---

**Допустим в item = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4] нужно вернуть только [4] так как ето дубликат**

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6]) === [1, 3]` - ??

Comment: Наверное, имелись в виду "неуникальные" значения без повторов

Comment: Нет там нежно уникальные значения. Там есть сптсание слева но по украински.

Comment: Вам удалить дубликаты нужно?

Comment: Ой, я совсем росстерялся нужно "неуникальные" значения. Допустим в item = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] нужно вернуть только [4]  так как ето дубликат

Comment: Простите item = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]

Comment: А что должно вернуть `getDuplicate({}, {})`?

Answer (score 0):

Если значения массива - примитивные значения, то можно так:

```js
function getDuplicates(arr) {
 return [...new Set(arr.filter((item, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(item) !== arr.lastIndexOf(item)))]
}

console.log(getDuplicates([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6]));
console.log(getDuplicates([1, 2, 3, 4, 4]));
console.log(getDuplicates(['last', 'ball', 'game', 'last', 'game']));
```

С объектами все будет сложнее.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!! Мне ещо нужен код, можно с вами как-то через еллектронную почту написать?

Comment: Нет. Задавайте вопросы тут, на сайте. :)

Comment: Дополни функцию getDifferences, которая принимает два массива, и возвращает массив различий между ними. Массивы состоят из уникальных значений.

Comment: ПРИМЕР: a=[1, 2, 3, 4], b=[2, 3, 5, 6] а вьіводить нужно [1, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: ВТОРОЙ ПРИМЕР:  a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], b=[5, 4, 3, 2, 1] вьівод []

Comment: См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1167148/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85/1167154

Comment: А вообще, это не так работает. Если есть вопрос - нажимаете кнопку "задать вопрос", и задаете, в соответствии с правилами сайта. :)

Comment: У меня не получаетса, или ето я не могу правильно переписать код или он не подходит. Напешите пожалуйста етот вариант для моего кода.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let arr = ['last', 'ball', 'game', 'last', 'game']

let arr2 = Array.from(new Set(arr))

console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: Немного не то. Я выше написал как должно выйти